# How to measure system network usage programatically in Java?

Tags: java, networking, monitoring

I'd like to obtain the host's full network usage, that is, the current upload and download rates. How can I do that in Java? If it makes that easier, assume the platform is Linux.

Comment: If you know how to use different network tool like netstat, then you can go for Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your network tool") and appropriately manipulate the result.

Comment: Can you give some example? Assume I don't know how to use a network tool...

Comment: @EduardoBezerra *Assume I don't know how to use a network tool...* The only assumption we can make is that you've done some prior research before coming here.

Comment: @JoshM This is pointless. This place is precisely a repository of answers. Having such an answer in site X is not a justification not to have it here.

Comment: @EduardoBezerra - But not a repository of answers for off-topic issues ... like "how do I use a basic network monitoring tool".  SO is a site for **programming** questions.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do that in Java?

Doing this in Java is a bad idea ... unless there is a strong requirement to have the information in a larger Java application.

- You can't do it in *pure* Java.  There are no standard Java APIs for accessing this kind of information.
- I Googled for something Java-specific and free that matched your requirements, but didn't spot anything. (YMMV ... please feel free to repeat the search for yourself!).
- There are OS specific tools for looking at network stats, etcetera, and one could attempt to run these tools as external processes from Java and "scrape" the output.  But that would necessarily be OS / tool specific.
- You could attempt to replicate what these tools are doing in Java, but this *may* involve native library calls, and would *certainly* be OS specific.  (On Linux, you may be able to get the information you need by reading from the `/proc` file system ... but there could also be access control issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Nethogs: http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/ is probably the tool you're looking for.

Most people use prefer this as it splits bandwith usage up by process.